# Fatal Exception running AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

I have a problem when trying to add the url to parse I get a `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask # 1` error and I don't understand why.

This is how I parse the data:

```
@Override
        protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

            tmoLectorClases.clear();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div");
                for (Element e : data) {
                    String urlRedireccionada = e.select("div.OUTBRAIN").attr("data-src");
                    try {

                        doc = Jsoup.connect(urlRedireccionada).get();

                        Elements dataNuevo = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                        for (Element e1 : dataNuevo) {
                            String imgUrl = e1.select("img").attr("src");
                            tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                        }
                    }  catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tmoLectorClases;
        }
```

The error `LogCat` me marks this line:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(urlRedireccionada).get();
```

With the **error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
```

What happens is that this `url`, it becomes this `urlRedireccion` and I try to load images from the `urlRedireccion` into a `RecyclerView`. Could someone tell me how to fix it? Debug the code and then, the url if it is valid:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is create a `String` with the redirectioned url :

```
String nuevaUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute().url().toExternalForm();
```

And after that, you will add to your `Document`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();
```